# TexMaker, permanent changing of the path

Tags: texmaker, paths

I just update my MacBook with the last OS El Capitan. I follow all the suggestion in order to make TexMaker work in a proper way, but when I relaunch the application all the changes in the paths are back as the origin so I always have to specify `/Library/Tex` instead of `usr`.
How I can make this changes permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by changing the path and save it under administration permission.